# Scala Play template vararg HtmlContent

Tags: html, scala, playframework, variadic-functions, twirl

I have a generic template in `play 2.6`, that I want to pass in a variable amount of `HtmlContent`s. I've defined the `template` like this (including the implicit parameter I have in case that changes anything):

```
@(foo: String)(content: Html*)(implicit bar: Bar)
```

On the template side, this works fine-- I can dissect `content` with `for` and render it as I want. However, I haven't been able to figure out a clean way to invoke the variable arguments from the underlying template.

e.g,  I have a view named "Baz":

```
@(something: String)(implicit bar: Bar)
```

In it, I try to invoke the `template` with multiple Html arguments. I've tried the following:

```
@template("fooString"){{123},{abc}}
and
@template("fooString")({123}, {abc})
and
@template("fooString"){{123}, {abc}})
```

And various other permutations, but inside of an enclosing bracket it seems to interpret everything literally as a single parameter in the `HtmlContent` vararg.

However, this ended up working as I intended, passing in multiple `HtmlContents`:

```
@template("fooString")(Html("123"), Html("abc"))
```

So that works, and I can use a triple-quoted interpolated string for a large Html block-- but it seems like there should be a cleaner way to do this, and the string interpolation is dangerous as it doesn't do html escaping.

Is there a way to do this using the `{` enclosed syntax? I'd like to understand more what is actually happening on an underlying level, and how play parses and generates HtmlContent in brackets.

Comment: Your `Html(...)` approach looks quite clean and explicit to me. The [Twirl source code](https://github.com/playframework/twirl) could be one place to try and dig further into your question though.

Comment: Any comments on the answer I posted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So consider you have below template

```
// main.scala.html
@(title: String)(contents: Html*)
```

There are different ways you can call this template

**Option #1**

This is what you already posted in the question

```
@main("This is a title")(Html("abc"), Html("123"))
```

**Options #2**

```
@html1 = {
    Hello
}
@html2 = {
    <div>Tarun</div>
}

@main("This is a title")(html1, html2)
```

**Option #3**

```
@main("This is a title")(Html(<div>Tarun
</div>.toString), Html(<div>
Lalwani
</div>.toString))
```

**Options #4**

This is not exactly same option, but needs change in Template signature itself

```
@(title: String)(contents: List[String])
```

And then calling it like below

```
@main("This is a title")(List(
  """<div>
     Tarun
    </div>
  """, """Hello"""))
```

**Option #5**

This requires code files and was already answered on another SO thread

[Paul Draper's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1212596/paul-draper) answer on [Why doesn't this pass multiple HTML parameters to template](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21105450/2830850)

Comment: Any explanation for the downvote? Its best to comment with a downvote